# Photoshop image becomes dull when dragging from one project to another

Tags: adobe-photoshop

When I drag an image from a project file to another, the color becomes dull and less vibrant. I'm wondering what's causing it? Both project files are in RGB mode.

Any advice will be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Different profile, different conversion intent, 10% contrast drop for higher dynamic range vision, other file showing cmyk simulation, adjustment layer...

Answer (score 1):

I was able to figure it out. I went to Edit>Assign Profile> And chose the same settings from the project file I took the image from.